# WPF setting IME to hiragana by default

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, ime

I have a WPF program where I set in code the ImeConversionModeValues to Native the following way:

```
InputMethod.SetPreferredImeConversionMode(TargetInputElement, 
    ImeConversionModeValues.Native);
```

The problem I have is that the Ime is not set to Hiragana and I need to change it through the language bar. I need Hiragana to be active by default.

What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct way - after setting PreferredImeConversionMode I added the call:

```
InputMethod.SetPreferredImeState(TargetInputElement, InputMethodState.On)
```